# Pyqt get pixel position and value when mouse click on the image

Tags: python, image, pyqt, selection, pixel

I would like to know how i can select a pixel with a mouse click in an image (QImge) and get pixel position and value.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any example that can run?

Answer (score 15):

```
self.image = QLabel()
self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap("C:\\myImg.jpg"))
self.image.setObjectName("image")
self.image.mousePressEvent = self.getPos

def getPos(self , event):
    x = event.pos().x()
    y = event.pos().y()
```

Answer (score 4):

This question is old but for everybody getting here, like me, this is my solution based on Jareds answer:

```
self.img = QImage('fname.png')
pixmap = QPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.img))
img_label = QLabel()
img_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
img_label.mousePressEvent = self.getPixel

def self.getPixel(self, event):
    x = event.pos().x()
    y = event.pos().y()
    c = self.img.pixel(x,y)  # color code (integer): 3235912
    # depending on what kind of value you like (arbitary examples)
    c_qobj = QColor(c)  # color object
    c_rgb = QColor(c).getRgb()  # 8bit RGBA: (255, 23, 0, 255)
    c_rgbf = QColor(c).getRgbf()  # RGBA float: (1.0, 0.3123, 0.0, 1.0)
    return x, y, c_rgb
```

Make sure the size of the label matches the size of the image, otherwise the x and y mouse coords need to be transformed to image coords. And  I guess it's also possible to use the `.pixel()` method directly on a pixmap as well, but the QImage object seems to perform better in my case.

Comment: What if the image was in gray-scale format, how can I get the intensity?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to draw the image. You can do this my making a `QLabel` widget and call `setPixmap`. You need to convert your `QImage` to `QPixmap` before doing this (you can use `QPixmap.fromImage(img)`).

You can get mouse clicks by subclassing the `QImage` and intercepting `mousePressEvent`. Look up the pixel value with `QImage.pixel()`.

Comment: Is there any short complete example that can be run in python? I don't seem to comprehend.